# Where to add fetch attribute - collection or association?

Tags: hibernate

Consider the following association:

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set name="addresses" table="PersonAddress" lazy="false">
        <key column="personId"/>
        <many-to-many column="addressId" class="Address"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="Address">
    <id name="id" column="addressId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
</class>
```

Now if I want to specify the `fetch = join|select|subselect` attribute, where do I specify it? The `<set>` element or the `<many-to-many>` element ?

Also, will there be any difference in the query generated?

Answer (score 0):

You have already set `lazy="false"`. This is equivalent to `FetchType.EAGER`. So u don't need to use `FetchType` again. `FecthType` is used in case of annotations and you are using xml based configuration.

---

As per your edited question, since you need `fetchmode`, you can define that by adding `fetch` attribute to your `set`

`<set name="addresses" table="PersonAddress" lazy="false" fetch="select">`

Your fetchMode determines the type of query which will be generated by hibernate.

A good explaination is given [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `fetch=join|select|subselect` attribute. Updating my question.

Comment: I understand what the fetchMode determines. What I am asking is will the generated query be different if the attribute is set in the `<many-to-many>` (or for the matter any association tag) instead of the `<set>` tag?